# Generalization of comparison theorem for improper integrals?

Tags: calculus

In Calculus (by Stewart) 7e, the Comparison Theorem is stated as follows:
[image]

I want to generalize it to:

Suppose that $f$, $g$ and $h$ are continuous functions with $h(x)\leq g(x)\leq f(x)$, if $\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ is convergent and $\int_{a}^{\infty}h(x)dx$ is convergent, then $\int_{a}^{\infty}g(x)dx$ is convergent.

Is this true? If not, could you provide a counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f-h \geq f-g \geq 0$. If $\int f$ and $\int h$ are convergent then $\int f-h$ is convergent and a) implies $\int f-g$ is convergent which implies $\int g$ is convergent.